# How to read attribute values from XML nodes with Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm currently trying to get a Powershell script to extract information from an XML file and I've been trying a few different things like Select-Xml and SelectNodes, but I'm struggling. The information is in a format like this:

```
<school>
   <students>
      <student name="Bob" subject="Math" year="5">
         <details SID="38571273" code="1122" group="" />
      </student>
        
      <student name="John" subject="Science" year="5">
         <details SID="38343555" code="1123" group="" />
      </student>
   </students>
</school>
```

I want to extract information like the name, subject, year, SID, code, and group and store it in an array for each student so I can process it. I'm writing a Powershell script to do this, but I'm quite new to it, as well as XML. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please post the actual XML, `SID="38343555"` is _not_ a valid tag name.

Comment: Fair enough. I edited the post. Forgot to add the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the updated XML I revised my answer -

I think this is what you're looking for. You would just have to update the path to your xml.

```
$XMLPath = "ENTER_PATH"
function Get-StudentInfo {
    param (
        $xPATH,
        $title)
    Select-Xml -Path $XMLPath -XPath "/school/students/$xPATH" | ForEach-Object { $_.Node.$title }
}

$students = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Names    = Get-StudentInfo -xPath "student" -title "name"
    Subjects = Get-StudentInfo -xPath "student" -title "subject"
    Years    = Get-StudentInfo -xPath "student" -title "year"
    SIDs     = Get-StudentInfo -xPath "student/details" -title "SID"
    Codes    = Get-StudentInfo -xPath "student/details" -title "code"
    Groups   = Get-StudentInfo -xPath "student/details" -title "group"
}

$students.Names
```

---

From there you would have an object `$students` that has properties with an array for each property.

```
Names    : {Bob, John}
Subjects : {Math, Science}
Years    : {5, 5}
SIDs     : {38343555, 38343555}
Codes    : {1123, 1123}
Groups   : {, }
```

To get a list of all the students names you would use `$students.names` or for subject `$students.subjects`

---

A version that loads the XML file only once, instead of once per call to `Get-StudentInfo`:

```
$students = Select-Xml -Path "test.xml" -XPath '/school/students/student' | Select-Object @(
    @{name='Name';    expr={ $_ | Select-Xml '@name' }}
    @{name='Subject'; expr={ $_ | Select-Xml '@subject' }}
    @{name='Year';    expr={ $_ | Select-Xml '@year' }}
    @{name='SID';     expr={ $_ | Select-Xml 'details/@SID' }}
    @{name='Code';    expr={ $_ | Select-Xml 'details/@code' }}
    @{name='Group';   expr={ $_ | Select-Xml 'details/@group' }}
)
$students
```

result

```
Name Subject Year SID      Code Group
---- ------- ---- ---      ---- -----
Bob  Math    5    38571273 1122      
John Science 5    38343555 1123
```

Comment: You probably want to parameterize `"test.xml"` too :)

Comment: Eh kinda pointless, since the XPath is only somewhat parameterized. Can only assume the file is one big file and not frequently changing, but easy enough haha

Comment: Tomalak's answer is def better! Should note that it needs to be declared as an xml object first

[xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path "C:\file.xml"

Comment: `Select-Xml` has the issue that it loads and parses the XML file from scratch every time, so for selecting 6 XPaths, you would load the file 6 times, which is a huge amount of overhead. It's better to call it *once*, just to retrieve the `<student>` elements, and then work with those after that.

Comment: Also, `[xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path "C:\file.xml"` is the wrong way to load an XML file. It will read the file with whatever encoding `Get-Content` feels like using today, ignoring the `<?xml encoding="..."?>` declaration, and thus silently mangling your data in the process if you're not lucky. The correct way is `$xml = New-Object xml` and then `$xml.Load($path)`. This parses the file *while* paying attention to its encoding.

Comment: ...a `Select-Xml`-based approach has its merits, being pure PowerShell without tapping into the .NET-based `XmlDocument` stuff while still using XPath to get the data. I'll add a concise version that does not suffer from the "multiple parsing" issue, if you don't mind.

Comment: Thank you so much to both of you! It really helped me and I was able to apply it to my problem and solve it. :)

Answer (score 3):

For simple tasks like this one, you can access the XML items with dot notation, i.e. `$xml.school.students.student` will give an array of `<student>` elements.

After that, you can use `select` (aka `Select-Object`) to pick out certain properties. Either direct properties by name, or name/expression pairs (`@{name='...', expression={...}}` for more complex ones, or if you want to rename the result "columns":

```
$xml.school.students.student | select name,subject,year,@{n='SID'; e={$_.details.SID}}
```

gives an array of `PSCustomObject`s:

```
name subject year SID     
---- ------- ---- ---     
Bob  Math    5    38571273
John Science 5    38343555
```